# Can a divorced woman talk to her ex-husband considering the child(ren) from that previous marriage?

Tags: nikah, talaq

A woman had married first time and had a child with that husband but then they divorced later. The woman married again.

Is she allowed to talk with the first husband because they have a child. And how the second husband should behave?

Comment: So it is not forbidden to talk with the x husband if the child has problem ect  is there anything for this kind of sugguations in kuran-ı kerim?

Comment: http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=142535 
It is in Arabic, in brief: he and she shouldn't talk except if necessary about the concerns of the children. please provide a better translation and add an answer!

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan not many here will be able to translate things from other languages.

Comment: @AlUmmat you are right, I will be very very happy when I find a time to this very wonderful, I will try to do the translation from Arabic as accurate as I can.

Answer (score 5):

Source: [Fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=142535)

Translated:

> If the woman is in her (['Iddah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddah)) than she is still considered married,
>   and it is ok for her husband to speak to her, even about his love for her,
>   for that might get her back with him.  But if the woman is totally
>   divorced, than the man must talk to her like he talks to any other
>   women. And it is ok to speak about things that are necessary, like
>   about the children for example.